# Join text together if condition is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Have a situation I am stumped on. The overview is I have a long list of employees with appropriate trainings. What I am looking to do is if "x" is in the box I want to join all text for all "x" values. Text values will be in row 3 in this example. I cannot seem to find the right solution, any help is much appreciated.

For this example Javier is where I tried to get something to work unsuccessfully. The output should be "CPR, 30hr, CP, HS, CT, R".

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igPdk.png)

Comment: if(A1="X", B1&","&C1&","&D1,"")

Comment: Ok that just sparked my mind:  Seems I have this working with the following, is there a better way? 
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(X3:AF3,X6:AF6="x"))

Comment: Up to you to do what works for you. I just went with what I thought would be simple to sort out.

Comment: Your FILTER version works fine, alternative could be `=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,if(X6:AF6="x",X$3:AF$3,""))` (note the `$`s for locking row 3 when you would drag then this formula)